# Android:Intent from Recycler View to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a recycler view that has many items that I want to intent from every item to specific activities. I tried many ways but all fail to intent to the activities.

This is the adapter:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> itemsData;

public ItemsAdapter(ArrayList<String> itemsData) {
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}


@Override
public ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent,
                                              int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String word =   viewHolder.txtViewTitle.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),word,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}




@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {



    viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData.get(position));
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.imsge_profile);

}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

 public   TextView txtViewTitle;
 public   ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.size();
}
```

}

---

This is `main_activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Toolbar tBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(tBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("AdroidCode Recycler View");
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    listItems.add("Tom");
    listItems.add("Hamdy");
    listItems.add("John");
    listItems.add("Hasna");
    listItems.add("Fadi");
    listItems.add("Samer");


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    ItemsAdapter mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(listItems);


    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


}
```

}

---

i tried this instead of the Toast but dosent work

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {          

    final Intent intent;
    switch (getPostion()){
        case 0:
           intent =  new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
           break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            break;
           ...
        default:
           intent =  new Intent(context, DefaultActivity.class);
           break;
     }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

new adapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;

    public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);

        recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final Intent intent;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(context, secoundActivity.class);
                        break;
                }
            }

            ));
        }}
}

List<Person> persons;

RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){

    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return persons.size();
}
```

}

Comment: And where is the Intent code that isn't working?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Does the app crash (if so, post a stack trace from logcat)? Is it some other error?

Comment: no there are many errors like cannot resolve the method getPosition() and cannot resolve symbol context

Comment: Put onclick in your main activity. If you use recyclerview in your recyclerview's item than only you have to put this in your adapter. Just think one thing, How can you set onclick of recyclerview where you have not find ID of that?

Answer (score 1):

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // do whatever
  }
})
);
```

I think you need to add click listener when you intialilize recycler view.Try these

Answer (score 1):

```html
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements
  RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
 private OnItemClickListener mListener;

 public interface OnItemClickListener {
  public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
 }

 GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

 public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context,
   OnItemClickListener listener) {
  mListener = listener;
  mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
      return true;
     }
    });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
  View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
  if (childView != null && mListener != null
    && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
   mListener.onItemClick(childView,
     view.getChildPosition(childView));
  }
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not direct use onclick. I have found a solution and it's works for me. Try it. I hope it will helps you.

Step 1: Fist add this RecyclerItemClickListener class to your package.

```html
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements
  RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
 private OnItemClickListener mListener;

 public interface OnItemClickListener {
  public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
 }

 GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

 public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context,
   OnItemClickListener listener) {
  mListener = listener;
  mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
      return true;
     }
    });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
  View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
  if (childView != null && mListener != null
    && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
   mListener.onItemClick(childView,
     view.getChildPosition(childView));
  }
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
 }
}
```

Step 2: Now use onclick method. this gives you position of item clicked. Once you get position than you can use it as per your requirement.

```html
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
   context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position + "",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 final Intent intent;
  switch (position) {
  case 0:
    Toast.makeText(context, "case 0",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    intent = new Intent(context,FirstActivity.class);
      break;

  case 1:
    Toast.makeText(context, "case 1",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
    break;

  default:
    intent = new Intent(context,DefaultActivity.class);
    break;
      
   }
  }));
```

Comment: thanks but the error is still exist the error in the method getPosition()

Comment: Hey you just have to use "position"  instead of "getPosition()". I edit my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: @HarviSirja position too gives me an error and completely failed to solve that error after many tries

Comment: please post your code. Because above code successfully works and I just check this for you. Give you code I will try to solve your error.

Comment: @HarviSirja I edited the details with my new adapter but always error in context and recyclerview in recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener

Comment: you put onclick in your adapter. This is onclick method of your recyclerview. so you should put it in your activity from where you just findID of your recyclerview. Remove it from adapter.