# Onclicklistener not working on recyclerview

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I am working with recyclerview the same code given below was working fine for me but
I have tried following code but it is not working

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.datelist);
    recyclerView.setClickable(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

in the Adapter

```
public  class UpdateHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener,CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        TextView uname;
        TextView uversn;
        TextView usitting;


        public UpdateHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            uname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_name);
            uversn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_version);
            usitting=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sitting_type);

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);
        }
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }
```

I have also tried the in Adapter in onCreateViewHolder

Please help me out

Comment: Where do you define your "isclickable" attribute? Please show your complete code and align it better.

Comment: please add whole code of adapter here

Comment: check my answer here. may be helps you .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821716/androidintent-from-recycler-view-to-activity/31825953#31825953

Answer (score 16):

For me, the solution was to remove the below from the `CardView` xml file.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Apparently, this attribute overrides any clickListeners added to the view.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that this problem occurs even when a child layout has has this attribute. That was my case.

Answer (score 3):

In recyclerView you have to create viewHolder like below code, you have to set click listener on viewHolder View as seen in below.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;
        private final MyEditText edtTest;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
            v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Demo", "Long click done bro--------------------->");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            edtTest = (MyEditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtTest);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }

        public EditText getEdtTest() {
            return edtTest;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Darshan Mistry : I think I have posted similar code given by you .

Comment: @Tushar, Please remove  implements View.OnClickListener write on click listner as  i write and remove also  adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this); and recyclerView.setClickable(true);